# Turn English Sentences into First Order Logic

Tags: java, nlp, first-order-logic

Do tools or libraries capable of translation an English sentence into First Order Logic exist?

Eg: 'Every thing that loves all humans is a dog.' becomes:

```
 ∀_(x,y)  humman(y)  ∩  love(x,y) → isdog(x)
```

I think it's called a semantic interpreter, but I don't seem to find anything beyond research papers.

I have just started learning both Java and Natural Language Processing, and I apologize in advance if my question has been answered before (Or if it's plain stupid).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Recommendation questions are not allowed on Stack Overflow. You can try asking on [softwarerecs.se], as long as you follow their own guidelines for questions.

Comment: This is not a software. This is an NLP tool. Wrong decision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at here: https://bitbucket.org/yoavartzi/spf

This is a very comprehensive package for parsing text, to logical form, mostly based on CCG grammar.

Comment: Hello Daniel. Thanks for your help. It fits pretty much what I wanted.